# How do I use helper methods from a devise mailer in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

At some point I found myself wanting to put some logic in a helper to call from my mail templates, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work.

`config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.mailer = 'UserMailer'
  # ...
end
```

`app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :users
  # Also tried:
  # helper UsersHelper
  # add_template_helper UsersHelper
  # helper :application
end
```

`app/helpers/users_helper.rb`:

```
module UsersHelper
  def drupal_password_reset_path(user)
    # ...
  end
end
```

`app/views/users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb`:

```
<!-- ... -->
  <p><%= link_to 'Change my password', drupal_password_reset_path(@resource) %></p>
<!-- ... -->
```

When it executes the template, it can't find the `drupal_password_reset_path` method.

What I do know from inserting some breakpoints and stepping around a bit:
* When `helper :users` is run, it is loading the right module and apparently adding it to the helpers correctly
* When the template is executed, *none* of the methods in `UsersHelper` are present.

There must be something obviously wrong but I just can't see it myself no matter how hard I look.

Comment: have you tried include UsersHelper

Comment: That's what `helper :users` is supposed to achieve. This was a long time ago now though and even I don't even remember how the problem was avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper UsersHelper
end
```

Also, I wouldn't use any helper method with _path in the name as it may conflict with Rails URL helper. Try changing your helper method name.

Comment: In 2018 I had said the problem was a long time ago and that I don't remember how we solved it, and now it's 2019, but my impression is that if we named a method like that, it was probably deliberately named to match the Rails helper methods, possibly even as a workaround for those not working for some other reason...